# text styling not working as expected in eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating a plugin like codeium I want to insert code when user types something and whne they press tab I will move the cursor to end of inserted code using the below code and it all works fine.

```
public class InsertCodeHandler extends AbstractHandler {

private static final String CODE_TO_INSERT = "public static void main";
private boolean tabPressed = false;
private boolean codeInserted = false;
private StyleRange styleRange;

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IEditorPart editorPart = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
    if (editorPart instanceof ITextEditor) {
        ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor) editorPart;
        IDocument document = textEditor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(textEditor.getEditorInput());
        int offset = textEditor.getAdapter(ITextViewer.class).getTextWidget().getCaretOffset();

        try {
            // Insert the code and set the background color to grey
            document.replace(offset, 0, CODE_TO_INSERT);
            codeInserted = true;

            StyledText styledText = textEditor.getAdapter(ITextViewer.class).getTextWidget();
            styleRange = new StyleRange(offset, CODE_TO_INSERT.length(), null, null);
            styleRange.background = styledText.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
            styledText.setStyleRange(styleRange);

            // Register a VerifyKeyListener to handle Tab and Esc keys
            styledText.addVerifyKeyListener(new VerifyKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public void verifyKey(VerifyEvent e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == SWT.TAB && codeInserted) { // Tab key pressed
                        if (!tabPressed) {
                            tabPressed = true;
                            // Reset the background color to default
                            styleRange.background = null;
                            styledText.setStyleRange(styleRange);
                        }
                        // Move the cursor to the end of the inserted code
                        styledText.setSelection(offset + CODE_TO_INSERT.length());
                        e.doit = false; // Suppress default behavior of Tab key
                    } else if (e.keyCode == SWT.ESC) { // Esc key pressed
                        // Remove the inserted code
                        try {
                            document.replace(offset, CODE_TO_INSERT.length(), "");
                            codeInserted = false;
                            tabPressed = false;
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

but until the user press tab I want to show some difference to the inserted code hence B added a vackground of grey but the background gets removed even before the user press tab key how to handle this.

Comment: You can't mess with the StyledText directly like this - the rest of the Java editor will not know anything what you have done and its styling will replace yours. You **must** use the extension points provided by the Java editor (or base text editor) to participate in the editor's styling code.

Comment: i tried with org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers extention point but no help . Can you give which extentions point to be used to acgieve this

Comment: Sorry but I am not an expert on the JDT extension points.

Comment: Maybe org.eclipse.ui.themes. Its description says: "This extension point is used to customize the appearance of the UI. It allows definition of color and font entities as well as theme entities. Themes allow applications to selectively override default color and font specifications for particular uses."